# How to produce an R count matrix

Tags: r, matrix, count, plyr

In R, I can return the count results using the specific column names I am interested in as an array as below.

```
require("plyr")
bevs <- data.frame(cbind(name = c("Bill", "Llib"), drink = c("coffee", "tea", "cocoa", "water"), cost = seq(1:8)))
count(bevs, c("name", "drink"))

# produces
  name  drink freq
1 Bill  cocoa    2
2 Bill coffee    2
3 Llib    tea    2
4 Llib  water    2
```

How can I get the count result of two specific column names in a matrix which has columns: all unique drinks, rows: all unique names and cells: freqs (like below)?

```
     cocoa  coffee tea water
Bill   2      2     0   0
Llib   0      0     2   2
```

P.S: Obviously, the solution does not need to use plyr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a contingency table, which you can create using `table`:

```
table(bevs[, c("name", "drink")])
#      drink
#name   cocoa coffee tea water
#  Bill     2      2   0     0
#  Llib     0      0   2     2
```

Comment: Thank you Roland. I edited my question: I actually want to be able to specifically name the columns I want to use (rather than bevs[,-3]), since my data.frame consists of many columns in reality. How can I do this?

Comment: I've edited the answer to accomodate this requirement. However, you might benefit from reading some introductions to R to better understand subsetting.

Comment: Yes, I realised from the fact that the modification I asked for was indeed very straightforward. Thank you!