# Return and count value from one column based on another column

Tags: r, sorting, counting

I know this looks like an easy problem - probably is an easy problem - but I have been googling for hours and I can't work it out.

I have a data set like this:

```
     Fav.Food    Fav.Col.   
1    Chips       Red
2    Bolognaise  Blue
3    Chips       Green
4    Chips       Red
5    Lasagne     Green
6    Crips       Purple
```

The question: all I want to is find all the people whose favourite colour is red, green, etc. then summarise how many of them like each different type of food (via a table() I'd assume).

I could just do this for each colour:

```
FoodForRed<-table(df$Fav.Food[df$Fav.Col=="Red"])
```

...then combine the answers into a data frame, but this seems very long-winded. What's worse is that I don't know how many different Fav.Foods or Fav.Cols there will be. I've been trying to solve it with a for loop that cycles through the Fav.Col column, but I can't get that to work and it doesn't look very elegant anyway.

Any help for a truly n00b question would be very much appreciated.

Edit:

It was pointed out that my question might be solved using [How to produce an R count matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044744/how-to-produce-an-r-count-matrix). That would probably work, but the far easier way was simply to use the table function alone:

```
 table(df$Fav.Col,df$Fav.Food)
```

It really was that easy...

Comment: `table(df)` is what you want, I think. If you don't like that formatting, try `data.frame(table(df))`

Comment: Oh my god... you're right. My real data frame has lots of columns, so I did `table(df$Fav.Col,df$Fav.Food)` and it gave me the right answers. I've wasted an entire morning trying to solve something that I could have just put into a formula. Wow. Thank you!

Comment: No problem :) Takes a while to get used to R syntax